# Android - Passing Object between activities error

Tags: android, android-activity

Singer Object :

```
public class Singer  implements java.io.Serializable {

    public String  id ;
    public String name;
    public HashMap<String,String> songs;

    public Singer(String name,String id){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.songs=new HashMap<>();

    }

    public void AddingSong(String songName,String songURL){
        this.songs.put(songName,songURL);
    }
}
```

MainClass:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //starting the mediaPlayer Activity with the song url
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), songs_page.class);

                intent.putExtra("name",(String)listView.getAdapter().getItem(position));
                intent.putExtra("id", songs.get(listView.getAdapter().getItem(position)));

                Singer Obj=new Singer("1","Bayan");
                Obj.AddingSong("koko","[song URL here]");
                intent.putExtra("Allsongs",Obj);


                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });
```

Songs Activity:

Singer singer =(Singer) getIntent().getSerializable("Allsongs");

Sending strings from activity to another activity was working , but when i wanted to pass object it is start give me an erorres.

Comment: You cant  pass the object via intent , you have to make it parcelable object and than pass via intent  !!

Comment: what errors exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a bundle:

```
Bundle data = new Bundle();
data.putSerializable("Allsongs", yourObject);

intent.putExtras(data);
```

Then in the other activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
Singer singer =(Singer) data.getSerializable("Allsongs");
```

Comment: Isn't it same as doing 
```intent.putExtra("Allsongs",Obj);```